# Is there a way to parse Json where a boolean value has no name?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Here is my JSON that I receive from the server. You will notice that the array of arrays 'rows' in the code below has a name value pair and occasionally a boolean value without name. I am having no issues parsing it with JSON that never contains the occasional `boolean`.

```
[{
    "label": "Overview",
    "rows": [[{
        "name": "name"
    },
    false],
    [{
        "name": "emailAddress"
    },
    {
        "name": "phoneNumber"
    }],
    [{
        "name": "website"
    },
    false],
    [{
        "name": "billingAddress"
    },
    {
        "name": "shippingAddress"
    }]]
},
{
    "label": "Details",
    "rows": [[{
        "name": "type"
    },
    {
        "name": "sicCode"
    }],
    [{
        "name": "industry"
    },
    false],
    [{
        "name": "description",
        "fullWidth": true
    }]]
}]
```

Here is my Java Code. I use Volley.

```
public void displayFields(){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext());
    String url = "some-url-goes-here";
    CustomJsonArrayRequest request = new CustomJsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("LoginActivity", "Recieved Success Response: " + response.toString());
            DisplayPanel[] displayPanels = new GSONBuilder().getDisplayPanelsFromJSON(response.toString());
            for(int i=0;i<displayPanels.length;i++){
                DisplayPanel panel = displayPanels[i];
                DisplayField[][] rows = panel.getRows();
                for(int j=0;j<rows.length;j++){
                    DisplayField[] fieldsinRow = rows[j];
                    for(int k=0;k<fieldsinRow.length;k++){
                        DisplayField field = fieldsinRow[k];
                        Log.d("LoginActivity", "Field has value: " + field.getName());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("LoginActivity", "ERROR getting jsonarray" + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    request.setCustomHeader("custom-header-name", "custom-header-value");
    queue.add(request);
}
```

In the code above `CustomJsonArrayRequest` simply extends `JsonArrayRequest` from the Volley library that only adds one method that allows setting custom headers. `DisplayField` is just a object that represents the name-value pairs in the json (right before the booleans)

```
public class DisplayField {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

DisplayPanel is the top level array items (contains label and rows). Here is the code.

```
public class DisplayPanel{

private String label;
private DisplayField[][] rows;


public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public void setRows(DisplayField[][] displayFields){
    this.rows = displayFields;
}

public DisplayField[][] getRows(){
    return rows;
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong? When I run this I get a

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: that doesn't seem like a valid json format

Comment: Exactly what I thought as well. However Jsonlint says it is valid.

Comment: use this: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Comment: at which line is throwing this error? is on `displayPanels.length` or in `rows.length`?

Comment: This is valid json.  Array elements can contain mixed types.  What is GSONBuilder?  That's not shown here and is therefore hiding the actual handling of the JSONArray.  I bet the problem is in there.